# Deleted config.php and now site is returning HTTP error 500

Tags: laravel

We lost our config.php file and the site instantly broke. We tried putting an empty config.php file but no luck. Restarted the server but also no luck. What's strange is that we didn't have a config.php file earlier that day. Our live app is running without a config.php as well.

To clarify, this file resides in /bootstrap/cache/config.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run `php artisan config:clear` from the command line to clear the config cache or `php artisan config:cache` to create a new config.php. Note that you need to use `config()` instead of `env()` in your code if you want to use config cache

Comment: php artisan config:clear gave an error back that was much more descriptive. We added a new provider earlier today and it was throwing a Undefined constant error. Removed it and it works again. Thanks!